# 5x5 square dot appears from skype check.js

Tags: javascript, html, skype

So I'm trying to add a simple skype call button to a page. It works fine with the exception of an obnoxious little white dot that appears at the bottom of the footer.

This is the script source:

```
 <script  src="http://download.skype.com/share/skypebuttons/js/skypeCheck.js"></script>
```

So in that script there's a detectionswf object, id is "skypedetectionswf". And there is also a div container for it that is also 5x5.

My question is how on earth do I hide this little zit?

I've put this directly under but it's no use:

```
<script> document.getElementById("skypedetectionswf").style.visibility='hidden'; </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use CSS:

```css
#skypedetectionswf{
    display: none;
    margin-left: -10000px;
}
```

Comment: Hot damn I'm stupid. Forgot that it was injecting html code into the existing one..... The wonders of javascript. Thank you thank you thank you sir.

Comment: What do you need `margin-left: -10000px;` for?

Comment: @AvL - Just to make sure it won't appear.